# Convert array<int^>^ to int*

Tags: arrays, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

how can I convert `array<int^>^` to `int*`?

Comment: C++ or C# or is this something like C#++?

Comment: It's C++/CLI, Microsoft's .NET extensions to C++.

Comment: Are you sure you need `array<int^>^`?  For example, C#'s `string[]` turns into C++/CLI `array<System::String^>^`, but C#'s `int[]` is C++/CLI `array<int>^` without the second `^`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be hard to directly convert `array<int^>^` into an `int*`, because it is an array of references to ints, not an array of ints. There is no promises about the memory layout of the integers themselves, which is required in order to get them to a plain old C/C++ array.

I think that the easiest way to go is to make a copy of the array, pass it to `f(int* input)` and then possibly copy the data back if it is modified by f.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot, at least not the simple way.

If you mean `array<int>^` to int*, you can do following:

```
array<int>^ arr;
cli::pin_ptr<int> pArrayElement = &arr[0];
```

and then use classical pointer arithmetic over the `pin_ptr`.

Answer (score -1):

Name of the array is the address of first element in the array.

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int* p = array;
```

Comment: Yes, we know. But this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: assume I have:
array<int^> ^p;
and I want to pass p as an argument to f(int* input);
what should I do?